# Validate CreditCard Number and checked radio button javascript

Tags: javascript

I have radio buttons radioVisa, and radioMaster. If either one is checked, I need to first check to see which one is selected and then validate that the card number entered is valid. I also need to make sure that only numbers are entered.... I am not allowed to use any regular expression techniques.... If the radioVisa is checked, it seems to work but when I added the code for the radioMaster, if it is checked it does't work.... Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please....

```
function isValidCardNumber(num, isVisa, isMaster){
var card = new Array();

    if (document.getElementById('radioVisa').checked){
        card  = isVisa;
        }
         if (num[0] != '4' ||  num.length != 16 ){

                return false;
            } else {
                return true;

            } else if (document.getElementById('radioMaster').checked){
        card = isMaster;
        }

         if (num[0] != '51' || num[0] != '52' ||  num[0] != '53' ||
 num[0] != '54' || num[0] != '55' || num.length != 16 ){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: this "num[0] != '51,52,53,54,55'" will probably not work as you imagine, google javascript in_array() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (num[0] != '51' || num[0] != '52' ||  num[0] != '53' ||
     num[0] != '54' || num[0] != '55' || num.length != 16 )
```

You can not combine all those numbers.You need to specify individually.

or

```
 var numbers= ["51", "52", "53", "54",55];
var index = numbers.indexOf(num[0]);
```

It will return -1 if that is not exist otherwise return the index

Comment: Thank you for that, but even after I do that, I still can't get it to work with the radioMaster being checked.

Comment: I don't actually have it online... If the visa button is checked it works, but when the mastercard button is checked, nothing happens, it stays false......i tested with 5412367986312465 as the dummy card number....

Comment: Just tested it again, and if i check either visa or mastercard, the only number that will show up true in both is if it starts with a 4... so if visa is say 4125963189643256 returns true and if i was to put that same number for mastercard it returns true, instead of false.